# How to get dropped File content with Fancytree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm using FancyTree to drag files from the user computer. All works fine until the dragDrop callback. Here I'm unable to retrieve the blob data of the dropped file.
Many other info are available into `data.dataTransfer.files` property as shown below:

[image]

Anyway I can't find a way to get the file content. I have to send the file to an upload service like Uppy File Uploader, so the file data is mandatory for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I discovered that my issue, more generically, was *How to get the content from a File Object in Javascript*.
And afterwards that [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is the best friend in such case.

```
dragDrop: function (node, data) { //dradDrop fancyTree event callback
    ...
    const current_file = data.dataTransfer.files[0]; 
    if (current_file != null) { //i.e. when another fancytree is dropped dataTransfer.files is an empty array
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.addEventListener("loadend", function (event) {
          file2upload = event.target.result; //This is the raw content of the file

          //For my purposes the following 3 lines apply a byte array to Blob conversion
          const binaryData = [];
          binaryData.push(file2upload);
          const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(file2upload)]);
       });
       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(current_file); //Read the File object as a byte array stream
 }
}
```

The above snippet is well commented, so I guess there isn't anything to add.